# Can I fix this problem in R or does this require setting up TLS encryption?

Tags: r, rodbc, sqlanywhere

I am new to connecting to the database in R. I am using a script where this code used to work but we recently did some updates and now it isn't working anymore. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: HY000: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]RAISERROR executed: TLS encryption is required for network database connections in CATAPULT 5.6.91.20 and later versions.
```

This is the code I was using to connect:

```r
ch=odbcConnect("myDSN",believeNRows=F)
```

I am wondering if we now need to set up TLS encryption and I would need to adjust the R code slightly.

I did try to change the above code to this:

```r
ch <-odbcDriverConnect(DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "dsn=myDSN;uid=myUID;pwd=myPWD;"))
```

I got the same error. I've tried this in RStudio as well as VSCode.

Comment: My guess is that the ODBC driver needs options to switch it to a TLS connection, which we can't see from here. I quickly googled `sql anywhere odbc options tls` and found some pages (SyBooks Online) that include https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/scplugin/config-network-page.html (mention of "packet encryption" including TLS) and https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/scplugin/config-odbc-page.html (allowing for custom certificates). I'm not sure if that applies to your ODBC driver, but it's a start.